# Finding all the functions in various modes assigned to a specific shortcut

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to find all the modes which do assign a function to some specific shortcut.

For example if I'm not mistaken a stock Emacs simply assigns (or defaults to) `newline` for S-return but while in org-mode `S-return` does invoke `org-table-copy-down`.

Is there an easy way to figure out which modes (both major and minor) do map a function to a specific shortcut? I can find all the shortcuts of one major mode using `describe-mode` but I'd like to find those for all the various modes. I don't mind if it were to only work for all the currently loaded modes.

Basically I'd like to find "free" or "relatively rarely re-mapped" key shortcuts, *which are also easy to type* (*i.e.* I'm not after doing "C-c a" because for a start C-c is a very convoluted key to reach and then having to then hit another key is one key too many for me.  I'm more after re-mapping `C-o, S-return, M-/` and other combo trivial and fast to reach).

Answer (score 3):

You can find the current-mode bindings using `C-h b`.
You can get all of the keymaps currently available, using `accessible-keymaps`. You can find all the features loaded via variable `features`. But you would have to work to find all possible bindings for all possible modes from all files that you have loaded so far.

I recommend that you do it for a particular mode, one mode at a time. It's easy to check a given mode's key bindings.

You can even check the bindings of keymaps (such as minibuffer maps or the Isearch map) that are hard to see otherwise, if you use command `C-h M-k` (`describe-keymap`) from library [`help-fns+.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el). I use that when I want to see what keys are still available in a given keymap etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

> M-x describe-unbound-keys

to find out the free  keys.

This is from third party library as said in comments.

Comment: Confirming whether you're recommending a standard library or a third-party library is always a good idea :) http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/unbound.el

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to your specific question, but I can give you my solution to getting easy-to-type keybindings that don't conflict with other modes.

In my set up, I've remappped CAPS-LOCK to Alt. Most people map it to CTRL, but I can hit CTRL relatively easily, while ALT is difficult. With this set-up, one of the easiest key combos to hit is M-space. So I use this as my own private keymap:

```el
(define-prefix-command 'ty-keymap)
(global-set-key "\M- " ty-keymap)
(define-key ty-keymap " " 'just-one-space) 
(define-key ty-keymap "j" 'join-next-line)
(define-key ty-keymap "s" 'mark-sexp)
(define-key ty-keymap "c" 'org-capture)
...
```

Note: by default, M-space is bound to `just-one-space`, which is useful. I've moved that to M-space-space. Bouncing my thumb twice on the spacebar is only a fraction slower than hitting it once, so it's not a big loss.

Since M-space isn't a keymap by default, this setup allows me to use all the keys on the keyboard, without further modification. That's a lot of real-estate, guaranteed to be free of any conflict with other packages - since well-behaved packages won't clobber a basic Emacs keybinding.

You might prefer another key combo, but the idea is the same. You could even use a function key as your prefix-command, so you could do `<f5>` followed by a letter for your commands.

Comment: +1 to both but that one is smart... Of course I'm already using Caps-lock as CTRL so I'll have to find something else.  I'll see what I can come up with but that sure seems convenient to have quick access to lots of free mappings : )

Comment: Just my two cents - I've got Mod4 (it's like alternative shift) on `;` key.
That's more than 30 single-key chords for the cost of one key. Also, Mod4 combines
with `C-` and `M-`, so there's 60 more shortcuts there.

Comment: @abo-abo That's an interesting idea! I'm not sure I'd use `;` as a modifier, but maybe as a prefix-command key. I'm going to play with that. Cheers!

Comment: @CedricMartin C-spc is bound to `set-mark-command`. I use this a fair bit, so maybe not a good one to shift. I have also played around with M-o, which I bind to `execute-extended-command`, i.e., M-x. I never use the command that is bound to M-o, and M-x is awkward for me to reach.

Comment: @abo-abo: yup this is great but... I've already got mod4 exclusively reserved to my window manager (hence I'm sure that my WM shortcuts won't clash with any app). So I guess I need yet another modifier ; )